# Validating uniqueness of attribute in error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a username attribute in my form and I validate it's uniqueness on my user model like this:

```
 validates :username, :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => {
      :case_sensitive => false
    }
```

However when I submit the form with the username input blank it display the errors messages:
**Username has already been taken** and **Username can't be blank**

The problem is I only want to display the error message that it the input is blank.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Granted this means using a gem, but https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form does this well and instead of throwing all your errors at the top of the form, it render's them out at each input. And like you want, it renders out one error per input at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use both validates and uniqueness then it display two error messages.

Instead of

> validates :username, :presence => true,
>       :uniqueness => {
>         :case_sensitive => false
>       }

Try to use the below :

> validates_uniqueness_of :username